# Can a proxy block specific webbrowsers?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a connection at my job trough a proxy server. When im trying open a website, for instance, www.stackoverflow.com in chrome it occasionally just jams and timeouts. At these times I have run som tests for instance I can open the page in mozilla and IE7. I can also do a tracert to stackoverflow or other sites. But I cant access the page through chrome. Is my ISP blocking me some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for a proxy to block based on the `User-Agent` header.
However, it would be rather unexpected.

Try submitting a request in Fiddler with various User-Agents.

What do you see in Chrome's Dev Tools?
What happens in Incognito Mode?
What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: I have installed one extension to chrome to resize the windows to test media queries other than that no extensions. It seams also this happens after having visited facebook allthough I can not be certain of that. I can visit facebook in other browsers though without problems.

Comment: At the moment I cant reproduce the error it is very strange. How do I go about to change the User-Agent header in fiddler.

Comment: Yes; that's Fiddler. Use the Request Builder tab. What happens in Incognito Mode?

Comment: At the moment the problem has temporarily vanished it seams as im writeing this from a chrome browser. The problem has been very sporadic. But an outage of chrome has always laste for 20 min or more. So I will test it the next outage.